# Install cryptography on rasperry pi 3

Tags: python, asynchronous, cryptography, raspberry-pi, modbus

i'm newbe with python.

I'm simulating the connection between server and client via Modbus. I do that with pymodbus library.

My server is an asynchronous server and i know that it's necessary install cryptography on raspberry to make it works.

I found these instructions and I followed:

-sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev;

-sudo pip install cryptography;

After that, i have an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "modbus_server.py", line 4, in <module>
from pymodbus.server.async import StartTcpServer
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymodbus/server/async.py", line 18, in <module>
from pymodbus.internal.ptwisted import InstallManagementConsole
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymodbus/internal/ptwisted.py", line 5, in <module>
from twisted.conch import manhole, manhole_ssh
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/conch/manhole_ssh.py", line 14, in <module>
from twisted.conch.ssh import factory, session
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/conch/ssh/factory.py", line 17, in <module>
from twisted.conch.ssh import (_kex, transport, userauth, connection)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/conch/ssh/transport.py", line 23, in <module>
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
import pkg_resources
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
import packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

I tried the same code python into Eclipse on Windows machine and it works.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing dependency

Run `pip install packaging`